# Load hashmap with values from another hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap1 < O1, O2 >

I want to create a hashmap2 < O1, O3> from the original hashmap1 where O3 is a field in O2.

I am aware that I could use the line of code

```
hashmap1.values().O2
```

to retrieve a collection of the O2 to be loaded but I'm having trouble piecing it together.

Do i really have to use a for loop for this process?

Regards.

Comment: Sounds like a poor encapsulation to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an entry set to iterate over the values:

```
for(Entry<O1,O2> e : hashmap1.entrySet()){
   hashmap2.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().getO2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Map<O1, O3> newMap = new HashMap<>(originalMap.size());
for(Entry<O1, O2> originalEntry : originalMap.entrySet()) {
    newMap.put(originalEntry.getKey(), originalEntry.getValue().getO3());
}
```